# Timeout waiting for a MongoConnection

Tags: c#, mongodb

Why does the following exception occurs from the Mongo C# driver while getting object from the MongoDB server?

> "Timeout waiting for a MongoConnection."

Is there a way to set this connection timeout somewhere or fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `socketTimeoutMS` in your connection string to increase the timeout.

Example:

```
mongodb://localhost/myCollection?socketTimeoutMS=60000
```

Comment: The error is about connection, so `connectTimeoutMS` argument is more appropriate here. `socketTimeoutMS` is by default infinity so your suggestion doesn't improve anything: http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/10/do-you-want-a-timeout/.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into this issue:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-406

The issue has been fixed and the fix will be included in the 1.4 release of the C# driver (coming out soon).

In the meantime, your best approach is to increase the size of the connection pool from the default value of 100, which is easily done on the connection string:

mongodb://localhost/?maxpoolsize=200

Make the connection pool size large enough so that there are more connections than you have threads running (or at least enough connections to satisfy all threads that need a connection at the same time).

Comment: It happened because there was a recursive reference in the object graph and it kept recursing and trying to pull from the server and it crashed. I had to go through the stack trace by increasing the timeout so enough stack trace was visible. Changing the property listed above increased the timeout. I will remember the maxpoolsize. It will become useful.