# Getting InvalidOperationException Exception from mongodb c# driver for queries that return large dataset

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database

I have a restful service in c#.net that talks to mongodb. When I return about 20,000 records to client the service works fine. But increasing the returned data set causes below exception on server side:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Server instance xxx.xxx.xxx is no
>   longer connected.    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.AcquireConnection(MongoDatabase
>   database)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.AcquireConnection(MongoDatabase database,
>   MongoServerInstance serverInstance

And on the client side I get:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.

Service works fine for small data sets.

Comment: How long does it take to return 20000 records?

Comment: @WiredPrairie about a minute

Comment: Try increasing the timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594273/timeout-waiting-for-a-mongoconnection